# how to create multiple id cards dynamically in fpdf using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I was trying to create  id cards using fpdf in which the data to be plased in the id card is coming from mysql database and i have successfully made it the problem is that i want to generate many id card like 10 id cards once and when i try the blow code it is generating the id cards but placing one on the other and i can only see the last id card:

A)so, how could i give them diffrent position for the id cards dynamically?
below is my code and image showing the output:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsvUf.jpg)

```
  <?php
         include('connect.php'); 
         require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');

    if(ISSET($_POST['generate_id'])){   
            $semsec = $_POST['id']; 
    $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `semsec` = '$semsec'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        // output data of each row
     echo '
                    <script type = "text/javascript">
                    alert("Student Not Found For The Provided Semister and Section");
                        window.location = "home.php";
                    </script>
                ';
    } else {

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $cls[]=$row;
    }
    $json=json_encode($cls);
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    class PDF extends FPDF
    {

    }
        $pdf = new PDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();

        foreach($obj as $item) {

        $name=$item['firstname'];
        $lname=$item['lastname'];
        $id=$item['student_no'];
        $semsec=$item['semsec'];
        $profile=$item['image'];
        $qr=$item['barcode'];

            $pdf->Image('images/background2.jpg', 10, 10,100, 50);
            $pdf->Image($profile, 80, 15,25, 30);
            $pdf->Image($qr, 15, 45,20, 15);
            $pdf->AddFont('courier','','courier.php');  
            $pdf->SetFont('courier','b',10);
            $pdf->SetXY(33, 22.8);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
            $pdf->Cell(9.5,7,$name,0,4,'L');
            $pdf->SetXY(33, 28);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
            $pdf->Cell(9.5,7,$lname,0,4,'L');
            $pdf->SetXY(33, 33.5);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
            $pdf->Cell(9.5,7,$id,0,4,'L');
            $pdf->SetXY(33, 39);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
            $pdf->Cell(9.5,7,$semsec,0,4,'L');

            }
    $pdf->Output();
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Please see about prepared statements in php/MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting the ID's on top of each other, without an offset for each one or a new page per ID.

If you want an ID per page you need to call `$pdf->AddPage();` after making each ID.
This will create a new page and set the XY to the top left of the page.

If you want multiple ID cards per page, for example X amount per page, split the array of id cards so you are looping over X amount at a time, the PHP function [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) would split it for you, and then just offset the XY coordinates by the amount you want to, so for example I did this

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

$farray = array_chunk($input_array, 2);
foreach($farray as $obj) {
    $yOffset = 0;
    foreach($obj as $item) {
        $pdf->SetXY(33, 28 + $yOffset);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
        $pdf->Cell(9.5, 7, $item, 0, 4, 'L');
        $yOffset += 40; // Y distance between letters
    }
    $pdf->AddPage();
}
$pdf->Output();
```